# Whole div is moving up when button is showing on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`. Hovering on it, I am showing a button. But when I hover on it, the whole `div` is moving little bit top. I don't know why is it moving It suppose to stay at same place when the button is showing. Here is my code:

```css
.singleItem {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19.80%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.singleItem img {
    width: 145px !important;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.singleItem p {
    margin: 0;
}
.singleItem:hover {
    background-color: #ff6622;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.singleItem button {
    display: none;
}
.singleItem:hover button {
    display: block;
    background-color: #cc4411;
    border: unset;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="featureProductItems">
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/iphone.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with it? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```css
.singleItem {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19.80%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.singleItem img {
    width: 145px !important;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.singleItem p {
    margin: 0;
}
.singleItem:hover {
    background-color: #ff6622;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.singleItem button {
    opacity:0;
    background-color: #cc4411;
    border: unset;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.singleItem:hover button {
    opacity:1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="featureProductItems">
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/iphone.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
    <div class="singleItem">
        <img src="assets/img/samsung-galaxy-tab-10.1.jpg">
        <p>Samsung galaxy tab 10.1</p><p>৳65,000.00</p>
        <button type="button">Details</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats a nice trick to solve the problem. Thanks. I will follow this. But the question remain, why it is moving up!

Comment: Because you add css on button hover you need to add directly to the button.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will mark it as a correct answer.